# How to stop click trigger and start a new one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a code for multiplayer game (tic tac two), normally on the first click the player 1 will play an X  then the 2nd player's turn will come but the problem is after the first player play the second click still an X it didn't change to O this is the "click " code that i create on jquery:
i which i can add the image of the page :(
html code :

```
<ul id="gamebox">
            <li class="box" id="1">#</li>
            <li class="box" id="2">#</li>
            <li class="box" id="3">#</li>
            <li class="box" id="4">#</li>
            <li class="box" id="5">#</li>
            <li class="box" id="6">#</li>
            <li class="box" id="7">#</li>
            <li class="box" id="8">#</li>
            <li class="box" id="9">#</li>
        </ul>
```

js and jquery code :

```
 function player1_turn(player1,id){
    var box_taken=$("#"+id).text();
    if(box_taken === "#"){
        count++;
        turns[id]=player1;
        $("#"+id).text(player1);
        wincondition(turns,player1);
        if(game_over===false){
            $("#message").html("Player "+player2+" it's your turn to play !");
            player2_turn(player2,id);
            wincondition(turns,player2);
        }
    }

}
function player2_turn(player2,id){
    var box_taken=$("#"+id).text();
    if(box_taken==="#"){
        count++;
        turns[id]=player2;
        $("#"+id).text(player2);
        wincondition(turns,player2);
        if(game_over===false){
            $("#message").html("Player "+player1+" it's you turn to play !");
            player1_turn(player1,id);
            wincondition(turns,player1);
        }
    }
}


$(".box").click(function(){
    if($("#message").text()=="Player "+player1+" it's you turn to play !" ||"PLAYER "+ player1 + " START PLEASE !"){
        var x=$(this).attr("id");
        player1_turn(player1,x);

    }
    else if($("#message").text()=="Player "+player2+" it's you turn to play !" || "PLAYER "+ player2 + " START PLEASE !"){
        var y=$(this).attr("id");
        player2_turn(player2,y);

    }
    });
```

Comment: you can use a Boolean value var xWasPlayed = true, then toggle it on each play? if xWasPlayed = true then  its O, if xWasPlayed = false then X. also, you shouldn't name your variables x & y, give them meaningful names,

Comment: A little confused on the approach. Not discouraging the approach, but what I would do Instead: Have a single click function that handles all box clicks. You can have a global variable that toggles values between Player 1's turn and Player 2's turn. Then in the click function, depending on who's turn it is / was fire the appropriate `player#_turn` method and toggle the global variable to the next player.

Comment: Instead of attaching the click event on `.box` class, you can add the click function to the `id` of `.box`.

Comment: Create the players (objects), add toggle between players at the end of the trigger. Add the figure X or O as attribute of the player, for example: player1.figure

Comment: @AndrewDaly 
I tried this method ,but when the condition is met, and the first player plays his turn, it does not stop to check the condition again. when i click in a new box it write X and not O.

Comment: Please update the question & add all of the code so we can see.

Comment: @AndrewDaly this a part on my html and js code